# What does cd myfolder/* do in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cd

I am new to Linux and have been using the cd command for a while. I just saw someone cd'ing to somefolder/* like `cd foo/*`. What does that do?

Also, depending on how that works, what will be the outcome of `cp -R foo/* bar` ?

Edit- If `cd foo/*` cd's into the first directory inside foo, shouldn't `cp -R foo/* bar` only copy the first directory present inside foo to bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` will be expanded to all items in `foo` and then you will `cd` into the first one of those items (which is hopefully a directory).

Comment: so shouldn't cp -R foo/* bar only copy the first directory inside foo to bar ?

Comment: No, that will copy all of them. When you use `*` on the shell, press Ctrl+X and then `*` instead of pressing Enter, this will expand the `*` and show you what will actually be executed.

Comment: The difference is that `cp` takes multiple arguments (filenames) and `cd` only takes a single argument. When the shell expands multiple filenames, `cd` will take the first.